# Gunicorn Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm setting up Gunicorn with my Flask application. I have the following file structure:

```
Flask/
  run.py
  myapp/
    __init__.py
    views/
      homepage/
        __init__.py
        homepage.py
      login/
        __init__.py
        login.py
      blog/
        __init__.py
        blog.py
```

The `run.py` file imports the app instance in `Flask/myapp/__init__.py` and runs it like so:

```
from myapp import app
def run():
  app.run()
```

Using the command line, I run `gunicorn run:run` and the website starts up. I go to the website and I get an internal server error stating this:

```
[2015-09-14 19:00:41 +0100] [35529] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/.virtualenvs/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/.virtualenvs/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: run() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

What is the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're supposed to pass [a WSGI callable to `gunicorn`](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn). As it turns out `app` is one, but your `run` function isn't.

So, instead of running `gunicorn run:run`, run: `gunicorn run:app`.